# How to pass a variable to add an if condition on a form

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I am working with Symfony2.
I have an EMPLOYEE entity(which has a string field 'category' among others) and a CONTRACT entity.

So,here is my problem :

After editing an employee, I can edit a contract for him.

I would like to add the field "salary" in my contract form if the employee belongs to the category == 'worker', and if category = 'CEO', I don't want to display this field.

Here is my ContractType :

```
class ContractType extends AbstractType
 {
    protected $employee;

    function __construct(MyBundle\Entity\Employee $employee = null) {
    $this->employee = $employee;
     }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('startDate');

        if ($this->employee !== null && $this->employee->getCategory() == 'worker') 
        {
            $builder
           ->add('salary', 'money', array('currency' => 'USD', 'required' =>false));                            
        }

        elseif ($this->employee !== null && $this->employee->getCategory() == 'CEO') 
        {
            $builder->add('salary', 'hidden', array('required' => false));

        }
    }
}
```

Here's my contract_form.html.twig :

```
 {% if employee.category == 'worker'%}
   <tr>
    <td>{{ form_label(form.salary, "Salary : ") }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.salary) }}</td>
   </tr>
 {% endif %}
```

After editing a employee and setting him category=='worker', when I want to edit him a contract, I have the error :

```
   Method "salary" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in MyBundle:Contract:contract_form.html.twig"
```

I am stuck with this error, I don't understand what is wrong in my code

Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `buildView` and set the variable on the FormView object. Here is an example on how it is done from [`CollectionType`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/CollectionType.php#L49).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is build your contract form dynamically according to your employee entity. IMO, you should use the form events which solves this use case.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html